# Displaying comments for questions only when they exist

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to display messages on a Django template.  Each message can have 0 to many comments. I need to display the comments for each message.  However, if a message has no comments, then it is 'None' and I can't iterate over it.  The problem is occurring in Django templates.

```
#models.py
class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    birthDate = models.DateField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    objects = UserManager()

class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "messages")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    objects = UserManager()

class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name = "comments", default = [])
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    objects = UserManager()

#views.py
#Main wall page
#Renders wall.html
def wall(request):

    wallDict = {
        "message" : Message.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, "loginRegApp/wall.html", wallDict)

#wall.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="/logout">Log out</a>
            <form action="message/create" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h4>Post a message</h4>
                <textarea name="message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Post a message">
            </form>

            {% for message in messages %}
                <div>
                    <h6>{{message.user.firstName}} {{message.user.lastName}} - {{message.createdAt}}</h6>
                    <p>{{message.content}}</p>

                    {% if message.comments %}
                    {% for comment in message.comments %}
                        <h6>Comment:  {{message.user.firstName}} {{message.user.lastName}} - {{comment.createdAt}}</h6>
                        <p>{{comment.content</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    <form action="comment/{{message.id}}/create" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Post a comment">
                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get all comments to display, whether 0 or 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.all` in your template to have access to the `QuerySet` that contains the comments. There is no need to use `{% if ... %}` and `{% endif %}`:

```
{% for comment in message.comments.all %}
    <h6>Comment:  {{message.user.firstName}} {{message.user.lastName}} - {{comment.createdAt}}</h6>
    <p>{{comment.content</p>
{% endfor %}
```

In your view, you might want to use [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) here to avoid making an extra query per message to fetch the related comments, like:

```
def wall(request):
    wallDict = {
        'message' : Message.objects.prefetch_related(
            'comments', 'comments__user'
        ).all()
    }
    return render(request, 'loginRegApp/wall.html', wallDict)
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that it was something so stupidly simple.  Thanks for your help.